# Can a non-enumerated device conduct DMA operations?

Tags: hardware, boot, bios, pci-e, bus

PCIe devices can read or write to memory, i.e. can do DMA without requiring a device driver.
If I remember correctly, if you flash a device's firmware (let's say an FPGA device) and input 0xFFFF as device and vendor ID, the device won't be enumerated by BIOS.
I am wondering, if a PCIe device can conduct DMA operations (memory read and write) by bus mastering even when it is not enumerated by BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

A PCIe device can only do DMA if Bus Master Enable (BME) is set in the command register. BME will only be set when a driver is active.

Comment: There are FPGA devices that can do DMA without a driver. They are controlled by another computer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fXthwl6ShOg

Comment: Why would the OS enable BME on a device with no driver loaded? That seems like an OS bug.